# emacs: Change case of a rectangle

Tags: emacs

What would be simplest way to change the case of a rectangle?

None of the short-cuts mentioned in the [manual](http://www.gnu.org/software/libtool/manual/emacs/Rectangles.html) talk about this. Do I have to add a custom binding to do that? And while we are at it, how do I search only within a rectangle?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's easy with using `cua-mode`'s rectangle selection support:

```
(setq cua-enable-cua-keys nil)  ; enable only CUA's rectangle selections
(cua-mode t)
```

You can then select rectangles by pressing <kbd>C-RET</kbd> and moving the cursor. To upcase that region, just use the usual `upcase-region` command, bound to <kbd>M-U</kbd> by default.

Comment: Yes and no. No because `upcase-region` doesn't work on rectangles, and `M-u` is `upcase-word` by default (`upcase-region` is bound to `C-x C-u`). Yes because when a rectangle is selected CUA binds `M-u` to `cua-upcase-rectangle` which, not surprisingly, works nicely. You can also use `(cua-selection-mode t)` in place of the code given.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification, Phil, and the hint about `cua-selection-mode`!

Comment: Thanks for the comment and clarification. But I find it a bit confusing(?!) that some thing this useful is not available out of the box with the other rect commands.

Comment: Agreed; I guess the standard `C-x r` rectangle support is pretty bare-bones. I've never used it personally.

Answer (score 12):

Here's an implementation of `upcase-rectangle`, which changes the case to all uppercase.  Just replace the `upcase` with `downcase` or `capitalize` or whatever custom case transformation you want:

```
(defun upcase-rectangle (b e)
  "change chars in rectangle to uppercase"
  (interactive "r")
  (apply-on-rectangle 'upcase-rectangle-line b e))

(defun upcase-rectangle-line (startcol endcol)
  (when (= (move-to-column startcol) startcol)
    (upcase-region (point)
                   (progn (move-to-column endcol 'coerce)
                          (point)))))
```